# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function _main

Tags: opengl, linker, glfw

This bit of code I followed from this [tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include "Test2.h"

using namespace glm;

int main()
{
    if(!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return - 1;
    }
}
```

And it generated an error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function _main

I'm using VC++ 2008.  I downloaded glfw-2.7.6.bin.WIN32.zip from glfw's official site, copied dll from the folder named lib-msvc90 to system32, and the lib to Microsoft SDKs. Any step I missed?

Comment: Did you also add the library to the linker definition.

Answer (score 2):

> Any step I missed?

YES

Please READ the 1rst tutorial. It explicitly states that you should use CMake instead of rolling your own Visual project. And there is no need to download GLFW, it's already bundled in external/. Same thing for GLEW and GLM.

There is also the [FAQ](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/faq/), and a [special tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/building-your-own-c-application/) if you really want to do it yourself.

Comment: I had so little understanding with this before, was jumping to what was familiar with me which was recreating it in VS. Doing it now, I stopped with the message : Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)... and more warnings.